# "Lengths" of Random Variables in Infinite Dimensional Spaces

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Consider a measure space $(S, \Sigma, \mu)$ and the normed vector space $\mathcal{L}^2(\mu)$.  Then for any measurable function $f: S \to \mathbb{R}$ with $f \in \mathcal{L}^2(\mu)$ the norm is defined as
$$
||f||_{\mathcal{L}^2(\mu)} := \left(\int_S f^2(x) \, \mu(dx)\right)^{1/2},
$$
and, as I understand it, this is exactly analogous to the "length" of $f$, just as the Euclidean norm is the "length" of a vector in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Now consider a probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P)$ and the normed vector space $\mathcal{L}^2(P)$.  Let $X: \Omega \to \mathbb{R}$ be a random variable.  Then for any such $X \in \mathcal{L}^2(P)$, we define the norm of $X$
$$
||X||_{\mathcal{L}^2(P)} := \left( \int_{\Omega} X^2(\omega) \, P(d\omega)\right)^{1/2} = \left(E\left(X^2\right)\right)^{1/2},
$$
but this is *not* the "length" of $X$ unless $E(X) = 0$.  Instead, we usually think of the standard deviation as the length of $X$ by subtracting $\mu := E(X)$ from $X$ first:
$$
std(X) := \left(E\left(\left(X - \mu\right)^2\right)\right)^{1/2}.
$$
This brings up two questions:

1. Why must we subtract $\mu$ to interpret this as the "length"?
2. I'm thinking of $\mathcal{L}^2(P)$ as a vector space over $\mathbb{R}$.  Since $\mu \in \mathbb{R}$, what does $X - \mu$ mean?  In Euclidean space, it doesn't make sense to write $\vec{x} - c$ for $\vec{x} \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $c \in \mathbb{R}$.

---

**Update** I want to be able to apply the intuition of Euclidean geometry to visualize things like the correlation coefficient $\rho$ as the cosine of the angle between two random variables $X$ and $Y$, as explained [here](http://www.johndcook.com/blog/2010/06/17/covariance-and-law-of-cosines/).  In $\mathbb{R}^n$ the cosine of the angle between two vectors $\vec{x}$ and $\vec{y}$ is related to their inner product and lengths by
$$
\cos \theta = \frac{\left<\vec{x}, \vec{y}\right>}{||\vec{x}||\cdot||\vec{y}||}.
$$
If $||X||_{\mathcal{L}^2(P)}$ were indeed the "length" of $X$, then I feel like I should just be able to change the norms and inner products, but I can't because
$$
\cos \theta = \frac{\left<X,Y\right>_{\mathcal{L}^2(P)}}{||X||_{\mathcal{L}^2(P)}\cdot||Y||_{\mathcal{L}^2(P)}} \neq \frac{\left<X - \mu_X, Y - \mu_Y\right>_{\mathcal{L}^2(P)}}{||X - \mu_X||_{\mathcal{L}^2(P)}\cdot||Y - \mu_Y||_{\mathcal{L}^2(P)}} = \frac{Cov(X,Y)}{std(X)\cdot std(Y)} = \rho
$$

---

**Update with picture** Here's my intuition for conditional expectations in $\mathcal{L}^2$, as requested.

[image]

Comment: Though I don't think the interpretation as "length" has too much use, what is your argument that we cannot interpret the L2 norm as length in a probability space?

Comment: @par I updated my question.  Thanks.

Comment: The $E[X^2]^{1/2}$ would correspond to the length of $X$ as in Euclidean Space. The standard deviation would correspond to the length of the vector from $X$ to its mean, in other words this is like length in the space of random variables modulo constants.

Comment: Using the standard deviation as the "length" instead of the $L^2$ norm makes the covariance the "inner product" to use to measure angles, instead of the $L^2$ inner product. (Note that covariance is actually not an inner product if random variables with nonzero mean are included in your space. Nor is standard deviation a norm, for the same reason.)

Comment: I think you're just trying to force an analogy that isn't really there. It's perfectly OK to think of the norm as the length of a vector in $L^2$, but the cosine of the angle between two vectors is just not the same as covariance.

Answer (score 2):

Length is not really the best way to think about norms in function spaces. It is much better to think of the norm as offering a vague notion of size. Thinking of the norm in function spaces as length just connotes too much geometric intuition where there is none. I think you are falling into a common trap when starting out in functional analysis, which is to try to interpret everything geometrically. I'll just say that this is a very problematic way to approach the subject and will cause you more headaches than it will insight.

The reason that the norm is always taken against the zero vector by default is because in vector spaces, the length of vectors is translation invariant. For example, in $L^{2}(\mathbb{R})$, we take the norm against the zero function by default
$$
\lvert\lvert f \rvert\rvert_{L^{2}}=\lvert\lvert f-0\rvert\rvert=\left(\int_{E \subseteq \mathbb{R}} \lvert f-0 \rvert^{2}\,  d\mu \right)^{1/2}
$$
but we could just as easily pick another function, say $g \in L^{2}(\mathbb{R})$ and write
$$
\lvert\lvert f-g \rvert\rvert_{L^{2}}=\left(\int_{E \subseteq \mathbb{R}} \lvert f -g \rvert^{2}\,  d\mu \right)^{1/2}
$$
which tells us how far apart these functions are in some sense (and there are many senses which do not coincide with your geometric intuition). Your standard deviation example just follows from the fact that you have a linear functional $\mathbb{E}[\cdot]:L^{2}(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathbb{P}) \to \mathbb{R}$ composed with another linear functional $\sigma[\cdot]:L^{2}(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathbb{P}) \to \mathbb{R}$ given by
$$
\sigma[X]=(\mathbb{E}[(X-\mathbb{E}[X])^{2}])^{1/2}
$$
and this has nothing to do with how vector spaces work, it is just because of how $\sigma[X]$ is defined. It is the "distance" (or how much "size" is between them) from the constant function whose value is given by the functional $\mathbb{E}[X]$.

As for your second question, like I said before, our brains are limited to visualizing in 3 dimensions. Trying to "visualize" in an infinite dimensional Hilbert space simply isn't going to work.

Comment: Thanks for the writeup.  I've thought that the geometric intuition was a big advantage with working in $\mathcal{L}^2$, though.  E.g., the conditional expectation $E(X \mid \mathcal{G})$ is the orthogonal projection of $X$ onto the space of $\mathcal{G}$-measurable random variables.  I can draw a clear picture of this, which is what I'm struggling to do above.

Comment: Well if you can draw what you describe, I'd love to see what you come out with.

Comment: I added a drawing of what I mean, with $\mathcal{G} \subset \mathcal{F} \subset \sigma(X)$.

Comment: I have to say, I pretty much disagree with this "nongeometric" view towards functional analysis. Sure, geometric intuition can be misleading in this subject, but a lot of the definitions in functional analysis, and particularly in Hilbert Space theory, are entirely motivated by geometric things. For instance, as bcf mentioned $E[X|\mathcal G]$ is an orth. proj. And I certainly don't think that viewing $L^2$ norms as a generalization of "distance" is necessarily a bad thing.

Comment: Calling it length or size is a semantics issue. Since this is not really a mathematics point but an intuition one, in my view the norm of an "intuitive" vector for example from $\mathbb{R}^n$ (although I find it funny that a 100000-dimentional real-number vector is considered intuitive, but lets stick with it) is its length i.e. a form of "measure" (oh dear...) of it's intrinsic size. Contrast with a metric space: in a metric space, elements are "points" so have no intrinsic structure: you can only measure the distance between them. So as long as you think of vector spaces as more complex

Comment: structures which have "internal" properties (size, length, etc.), you are in the right "intuitive" direction. But you also have the whole parallel topic of "measure", compared with norm here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1483770/difference-between-a-measure-and-a-norm-in-a-euclidean-space/2563211

Answer (score 0):

Let $V$ be a vector space. Examples of $V$ are,  $V=\mathcal{R}^n$, the n-dimensional space of reals  or $V=L^2(\mu)=\{f:\int f^2 d\mu<\infty\}$.

A norm $\vert\vert\cdot\vert\vert$ is non negative real-valued function on $V$ which satisfies the three well known properties.

For  $f\in L^2(\mu)$, a norm is  $\vert\vert f\vert\vert_2=(\int f^2 d\mu)^{1/2}$.

In a Euclidean space,  for  $x=(x_1,\ldots,x_n) \in \mathcal{R}^n$ a  norm is defined as $\vert\vert x\vert\vert=(\sum^{n}_{i=1}x_i^2)^{1/2}$

In a normed space there is an induced metric(a "distance" between its elements) defined by: $\vert\vert v-w\vert\vert,\;v,w\in V$.

For  $f,g\in L^2(\mu)$,  $\vert\vert f-g\vert\vert_2=(\int (f-g)^2 d\mu)^{1/2}$
and for $x,y\in \mathcal{R}^n$  the induced metric is $\vert\vert x-y\vert\vert=(\sum^{n}_{i=1}(x_i-y_i)^2)^{1/2}$ which is the well known Euclidean distance between two vectors.

So, the  length of a vector  is actually  the  Euclidean norm  on  $\mathcal{R}^n$.

The variance is a  special case.    $X\in \mathcal{R}$  is random  variable ie a measurable function $\mu\in \mathcal{R}$  is a constant, the expectation of $X$, and $P$ is a probability  measure on $X$ then  $$Var(X)=\vert\vert X-\mu\vert\vert_2^2=\int(X-\mu)^2dP=E(X-\mu)^2$$

The standard deviation is the actual norm.

The covariance between two random variables $X,Y$ is the inner product $<X-E(X),Y-E(Y)>\;=\int (X-E(X))(Y-E(Y))dP$.

Notice that this inner product can produce the $L_2(P)$ norm   as special case  for $X=Y,\;E(X)=0$. 
 $$<X,X>\;=\int X^2 dP=\vert\vert X\vert\vert_2^2$$
This is  the known formula  $Cov(X,X)=Var(X)$.

In general norms in  $L_2(P)$ spaces cannot be produced from an inner product.

Answer (score 0):

I think @ian answered the question in the comments to OP's post, but here I will rephrase it:

Since the covariance map $ cov(X,Y) \to \mathbb{E}[(X - \mathbb{E}[X])(Y - \mathbb{E}[Y])]$ is actually an inner product [as shown here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2438924/74862), it induces the norm which is precisely the standard deviation map $ sd(X) \to (\mathbb{E}[(X - \mathbb{E}[X])^2])^{\frac{1}{2}}$, which in turn induces a metric etc. As someone already explained in another answer, for your geometric intuition: random variables for which $\mathbb{E}[X] \ne 0$ can be though of as "translated" versions of their $0$-mean counterparts, which is why the $\mathbb{E}[X]$ "creeps in" to the formula above.